# Geometry page numbering problem

Tags: page-numbering, geometry

I've just started using LaTeX and I'm having a problem writing an article for school. My problem is that in the output pdf, only the first page is numbered, while the other pages have no number written on them. Can somebody help? I think the problem is with the geometry package (when I remove it from the preamble, the numbers on the pages appear again, but as LyX uses this package I'd like to keep it because then it's easier for me to do stuff).
Btw, if you need to know, I'm using Overleaf.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,italian]{amsart}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm,headheight=2cm,headsep=2cm,footskip=1cm}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=false]{hyperref}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  If you issue the command `\pagestyle{plain}` after loading `geometry`, page numbers should be restored, at the bottom of the pages.  Off topic: `amsart` has its own method of adjusting page sizes, and it's usually not recommended to use `geometry`, but since this document won't be submitted to an AMS journal, that shouldn't matter.

Comment: If I use your preamble I get  page number 1 at the bottom of page 1 and page numbers 2,3,4 at the top right of the page head on later pages